# I have a UIButton inside a CollectionViewCell which is again inside the TableViewCell.How do i navigate to next view contoller by clicking UIButton?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have `UIButton` inside `UICollectionViewCell` which is inside `UITableViewCell`, I need to navigate another `UIViewController` on tapping that `UIButton`. But `UINavigationController` is not working inside the `UICollectionViewCell`. Can anybody please help?

I do not find any navigationController in my code.

```
import UIKit

class TrendingProductTVCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var trendingProductCV: UICollectionView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        trendingProductCV.delegate = self
        trendingProductCV.dataSource = self
    }
}


extension TrendingProductTVCell: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = trendingProductCV.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "TrendingProductsCVCell", for: indexPath) as? TrendingProductsCVCell
        cell?.trendingAddToCartBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addToCartBtnTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        return cell!
    }

    @objc
    func addToCartBtnTapped(sender: UIButton){
       let productDetail = trendingProductsDataArray[sender.tag]
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add navigation controller in storyboard and then you can refer self.navigationcontroller push. Also, you suppose to extension  datasource methods on you view controller class.

Answer (score 3):

You can use delegate protocol.

```
protocol TrendingProductTVCellDelegate {
    func addToCart(product: Product)
}

class TrendingProductTVCell: UITableViewCell {
    var delegate: TrendingProductTVCellDelegate?
}

extension TrendingProductTVCell: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    @objc func addToCartBtnTapped(sender: UIButton){
       let productDetail = trendingProductsDataArray[sender.tag]
       delegate?.addToCart(product: productDetail)
    }
}
```

UINavigationController can only be accessed via ViewController. So your TrendingProductViewController have to listen to the protocol, then now you can access navigationController.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = ... // your TrendingProductTVCell
    cell.delegate = self // <- important
    ...
}

extension TrendingProductViewController: TrendingProductTVCellDelegate {
    func addToCart(product: Product) {
        navigationController.push() // your rest code here....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do either of the two things 
 1. Post a notification using **NotificationCenter**, send in your
    **productDetail** in the **userInfo** and listen for the notification in the **ViewController** which is containing your **tableView**
 2. Or, you can simply create a **Protocol** with the method you want to fire when a product is selected, add in a **delegate** property in the **TableViewCell**, send in your controller's reference when you create your cell (in **cellForRowAt:**), and call in the method on that **delegate** when a product is selected.

Although I prefer to use the second method, but in both the ways you will be able to handle the pushing of your new view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Using Delegate: Via delegate, you can provide more info to the caller and it is more flexible in this case. Best solution use delegate.

Answer (score 0):

You can get parentViewController for any view using this extension:

```
extension UIView {
  var parentViewController: UIViewController? {
    var parentResponder: UIResponder? = self
    while parentResponder != nil {
        parentResponder = parentResponder!.nextResponder()
        if parentResponder is UIViewController {
            return parentResponder as! UIViewController!
        }
    }
    return nil
  }
}
```

Then you'll be able to access parentViewController inside `UITableViewCell` OR `UICollectionViewCell`. Get navController for this parentViewController and push to next one from inside `UICollectionViewCell`.